# Quanteda changing rel freq of a term over time

Tags: r, nlp, quanteda

I have a corpus of news articles with date and time of publication as 'docvars'.

```
readtext object consisting of 6 documents and 8 docvars.
# Description: df[,10] [6 × 10]
  doc_id               text        year month   day  hour minute second title        source
* <chr>                <chr>      <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int>  <int> <chr>        <chr> 
1 2014_01_01_10_51_00… "\"新华网伦敦1…  2014     1     1    10     51      0 docid报告称若不减… RMWenv
2 2014_01_01_11_06_00… "\"新华网北京1…  2014     1     1    11      6      0 docid盘点2013… RMWenv
3 2014_01_02_08_08_00… "\"原标题：报告…  2014     1     2     8      8      0 docid报告称若不减… RMWenv
4 2014_01_03_08_42_00… "\"地球可能毁灭…  2014     1     3     8     42      0 docid地球可能毁灭… RMWenv
5 2014_01_03_08_44_00… "\"北美鼠兔看起…  2014     1     3     8     44      0 docid北美鼠兔为应… RMWenv
6 2014_01_06_10_30_00… "\"欣克力C点核…  2014     1     6    10     30      0 docid英国欲建50… RMWenv
```

I would like to measure the *changing* relative frequency that a particular term - e.g 'development' - occurs in these articles (either as a proportion of the total terms in the article / or as a proportion of the total terms in all the articles published in a particular day / month). I know that I can count the number of times the term occurs in all the articles in a month, using:

`dfm(corp, select = "term", groups = "month")`

and that I can get the relative frequency of the word to the total words in the document using:

`dfm_weight(dfm, scheme = "prop")`

But how do I combine these together to get the frequency of a specific term relative to the total number of words on a particular day or in a particular month?

What I would like to be able to do is measure the change in the amount of times a term is used over time, but accounting for the fact that the total number of words used is also changing. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect someone will come up with a better solution within `quanteda`, but in the event they don't, you could always extract the word from the `dfm` and put it in a dataset along with the date and then make the graph.  In the code below, I'm using some music reviews I scraped from the Guardian's website.  I've commented out the functions that read in the data from an `.rda` file from Dropbox.  You're welcomed to use it if you like - it's clean, but I don't want to inadvertently have someone download a file from the web they're not aware of.

```
# f <- file("https://www.dropbox.com/s/kl2cnd63s32wsxs/music.rda?raw=1")
# load(f)
## create corpus and dfm
corp <- corpus(as.character(m$body_text))
docvars(corp, "date") <- m$first_publication_date
D <- dfm(corp, remove=stopwords("english"))

## take word frequencies "wonderfully" in the dfm
## along with the date
tmp <- tibble(
  word = as.matrix(D)[,"wonderfully"], 
  date = docvars(corp)$date, 
  ## calculate the total number of words in each document
  total = rowSums(D)
)


tmp <- tmp %>% 
  ## turn date into year-month
  mutate(yearmon =zoo::as.yearmon(date)) %>% 
  ## group by year-month
  group_by(yearmon) %>% 
  ## calculate the sum of the instances of "wonderfully" 
  ## divided by the sum of the total words across all 
  ## documents in the month
  summarise(prop = sum(word)/sum(total))

## make a plot.
ggplot(tmp, aes(x=yearmon, y=prop)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  labs(x= "Date", y="Wonderfully/Total # Words")
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you, that’s exactly what I was looking for... and a great clear example of how to do it too.

Answer (score 4):

@DaveArmstrong gives a good answer here and I upvoted it, but can add a bit of efficiency using some of the newest **quanteda** syntax, which is a bit simpler.

The key here is preserving the date format created by `zoo::yearmon()`, since the dfm grouping coerce that to a character.  So we pack it into a docvar, which is preserved by the grouping, and then retrieve it in the `ggplot()` call.

```r
load(file("https://www.dropbox.com/s/kl2cnd63s32wsxs/music.rda?raw=1"))

library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.1.1

## create corpus and dfm
corp <- corpus(m, text_field = "body_text")
corp$date <- m$first_publication_date %>%
  zoo::as.yearmon()
D <- dfm(corp, remove = stopwords("english")) %>%
  dfm_group(groups = "date") %>%
  dfm_weight(scheme = "prop")

library("ggplot2")
convert(D[, "wonderfully"], to = "data.frame") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = D$date, y = wonderfully, group = 1)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Wonderfully/Total # Words")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Ken.  I was hoping someone would post the Quanteda way of doing it.  That looks great.

Comment: Thank you both! The two solutions were both useful to me in helping me to do the analysis I wanted.

Comment: Is there any way to add multi word expression into the dfm count? Following your advice before, I'd been using spacy_tokenize and `tokens_compound(pattern = phrase("抗美 援朝"), concatenator = " ")` to add these into a dfm of a 'tokens' object, but here the dfm is on a 'corpus' instead? It would be amazing if I could also count the relative frequency of these custom defined expressions!